# How do I align columns in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, export-to-csv, export-to-excel

My code uses pySimpleGUI. In this sample, I have removed lots of stuff not necessary for this question, so the GUI only leaves one set of options that need to be selected, which then try to download and output to Excel a whole "Group of DRGs" (group 'Z', which I made up for this question).

It creates an Excel spreadsheet named 'output2.xlsx' and it outputs data to 3 sheets, as directed. However, it only outputs the last item, presumably overwriting the previous ones.

I have chosen to output to Excel and not csv, because it's more than just a 2D table. However, in the last step I'm attempting to also output to csv and there we get the same problem: only a table for one of the 'DRGs' is in there.

In another question I'm asking how to ensure that all the rows of data collected get outputted to the Excel. But in this question, I'd like to ask:

As the 'DRGs' have data starting and ending in different years, how can I align all the years in my output (or in my dataframe)? (So that data for year 2014 goes into the 2014 column, even if another row of data starts at year 2009, etc.)

This is my dictionary file, which is named jgp_dict.py and contains a 'group of DRGs'

```
jgps = {
    'jgp_dict_Z': {
        'A01 ZABIEGI WEWNĄTRZCZASZKOWE Z POWODU POWAŻNEGO URAZU': '5.51.01.0001001',
        'A02 ZABIEGI WEWNĄTRZCZASZKOWE Z POWODU URAZU': '5.51.01.0001002',
        'A87B INNE CHOROBY UKŁADU NERWOWEGO<18 R.': '5.51.01.0001089'
        }
    }
```

And here the actual file, as mentioned, it's stripped of lots of options in the GUI, that's why it looks weird:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import PySimpleGUI as sg
from jgp_dict import jgps

layout = [
[sg.Text("This tool will scrape selected data for all hospitals and for private hospitals countrywide for all available years")],
[sg.Text("It will output a csv file containing the scraped data and place it in the directory where the tool is saved")],
[sg.Text("")],
[sg.Text("Select Catalogue")],
[sg.Combo(['1a - JGP / DRG'], default_value='Select 1 of 4 catalogues', s=(55,22), enable_events=True, readonly=True, k='-CATALOG-')],
[sg.Text("Select Group / field")],
[sg.Listbox(['Z - Kompleksowa diagnostyka onkologiczna'], s=(55,4), no_scrollbar=True, enable_events=True, k='-GROUP-')],
[sg.Text("You can Select a specific DRG or Scrape a whole Group / field (within 1a / 1b)")],
[sg.Text("In the short Catalogues 1d & 1w you can only scrape the entire Catalogue")],
[sg.Listbox(['Scrape whole Group of DRGs in 1a / field in 1b'], no_scrollbar=True, enable_events=True, s=(55,2), k='-DETAIL-')],
[sg.Text("Select DRG / service")],
[sg.Combo([], default_value='Select DRG / service', s=(80,22), enable_events=True, readonly=True, k='-DRG-')],
[sg.Text("Select required data")],
[sg.Listbox(['Volumes, Values, Duration'], no_scrollbar=True, enable_events=True, s=(25,2), k='-METHOD-')],
[sg.Text("If happy with your selections, click Scrape, otherwise modify above or Quit")],
[sg.Button('Scrape', k='-GO-'), sg.Button('Quit', k='-QUIT-')],
[sg.Text("After clicking Scrape, WAIT for the programme to carry out the process")]]

window = sg.Window('NFZ Hospital DRG Data Scraper',layout)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED or event == '-QUIT-':
        break

    if event == '-GO-':
        event, values = window.read()
        method = str(values['-METHOD-'][0])
        url = "https://statystyki.nfz.gov.pl/Benefits/CrossSectionalAnalysisData"
        list_range = ['2', '']

        if values['-CATALOG-'] == '1a - JGP / DRG':
            det = str(values['-DETAIL-'][0])
        else:
            det = 'Scrape whole Group of DRGs in 1a / field in 1b'

        if det == 'Scrape whole Group of DRGs in 1a / field in 1b':
            if method == 'Volumes, Values, Duration':

                list_Group = list(jgps['jgp_dict_Z'].values())
                all_data_set = []

                for z in list_Group:
                    ProductCode_All = z

                    Dataset1 = "0"
                    all_data1 = []
                    year_data1 = []
                    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output2.xlsx', engine = 'xlsxwriter')

                    for x in list_range:
                        querystring = {"show":"true","P.ProductCode":ProductCode_All,"P.Dataset":Dataset1,"P.FirstType":"Line","P.Branch":"","P.HospitalType":f"{x}"}
                        payload = ""
                        r = requests.request("GET", url, data=payload, params=querystring)
                        data1 = r.json()
                        year_data1 = data1['labels']
                        for a in data1['datasets']:
                            all_data1.append(a["data"])
                    val_df1 = pd.DataFrame((all_data1), index=["Hospitalisation Volume - Private", "Hospitalisation Volume - All"], columns=year_data1)
                    print(val_df1)
                    val_df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'volumes')
                    all_data_set.append(val_df1)

                    Dataset4 = "4"
                    all_data4 = []
                    year_data4 = []

                    for x in list_range:
                        querystring = {"show":"true","P.ProductCode":ProductCode_All,"P.Dataset":Dataset4,"P.FirstType":"Line","P.Branch":"","P.HospitalType":f"{x}"}
                        payload = ""
                        r = requests.request("GET", url, data=payload, params=querystring)
                        data4 = r.json()
                        year_data4 = data4['labels']
                        for a in data4['datasets']:
                            all_data4.append(a["data"])
                    val_df4 = pd.DataFrame((all_data4), index=["Hospitalisation Days (median) - Private", "Hospitalisation Days (median) - All"], columns=year_data4)
                    print(val_df4)
                    val_df4.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'duration')
                    all_data_set.append(val_df4)

                    Dataset6 = "6"
                    all_data6 = []
                    year_data6 = []

                    for x in list_range:
                        querystring = {"show":"true","P.ProductCode":ProductCode_All,"P.Dataset":Dataset6,"P.FirstType":"Line","P.Branch":"","P.HospitalType":f"{x}"}
                        payload = ""
                        r = requests.request("GET", url, data=payload, params=querystring)
                        data6 = r.json()
                        year_data6 = data6['labels']
                        for a in data6['datasets']:
                            all_data6.append(a["data"])
                    val_df6 = pd.DataFrame((all_data6), index=["Hospitalisation Value (PLN) - Private", "Hospitalisation Value (PLN) - All"], columns=year_data6)
                    print(val_df6)
                    val_df6.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'values')
                    writer.close()
                    all_data_set.append(val_df6)

                frames = [val_df1, val_df6, val_df4]
                df = pd.concat(frames)
                df.to_csv('output_vol-val-Group2.csv', header=True, encoding = 'utf-8-sig', na_rep = 'N/A')

                print(df)
window.close()
```

Comment: try to simplify and give something that is more distilled down to just your question. see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thank you Jazz. I've already stripped it of loads of optionality and reduced by about 200 lines and two dictionaries, to leave only one option. But I'll try to perhaps get rid of the GUI entirely, as obviously the length is turning off potential helpers. Thanks for your message.

Comment: you're welcome. and yeah the key here is trying to distill it down to the specific question you are trying to ask / problem that you are having. From reading it, it sounds more like a question about dataframes then about the GUI. If so, make a minimal example of what you're trying to do in pandas / dataframe land.